# How to clone a directory with different name locally with Git / SourceTree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Being a complete noob in git, I have the following question:

I am using `SourceTree` and `BitBucket`.

I'd like to do `clone` and in the future `git pull` a repo, with root directory name `hello`. However, on my local machine I need the root directory to have name `hello_world`, in order for stuff to work properly.

How can I do this?

Optionally, I can download the directory and rename it manually. If so, then how do I "connect" it to the existing git repo, using SourceTree?

Comment: In Sourcetree, you should just be able to open any directory which is a valid git repo, regardless of its name. In git you can clone into a specific directory using `git clone git@github.com:whatever folder-name`

Comment: I don't think you got my problem.

Comment: I want to "connect" my local folder to an existing repo from my bitbucket account.

Comment: Yeah, I understant, I was just saying, clone your repo to wherever you'd like it (with the command I shared), then just open it in SourceTree - done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Specifying Git Directory

You can specify which directory you'd like to clone your repository into with the command line using:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:teamsinspace/documentation-tests.git folder-name
```

Alternativley, just move the `.git` folder to wherever you'd like the root of your project to be.

### Opening repo in SourceTree

You can also rename any Sourcetree-cloned repo, and just reopen it in Sourcetree. In order to do this:

1. Click on "Clone/New".
2. Click on the "Add Working Copy" tab.
3. In the Working Copy Path section, insert your local repository folder path

   - If it is either a Git or Hg repository, it will be stated as so as
     the "Repository Type";
   - else it'll state that it is an invalid path.
4. Click "Add" to confirm adding the local repository.

### Additional Links

- Have a read of the [documentation for cloning BitBucket into SourceTree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html)
- [How can I change the path of a project in SourceTree?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-can-I-change-the-path-of-a-project-in-SourceTree/qaq-p/290912)
- [Clone a repository into SourceTree Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/clone-a-repository-into-sourcetree-780870050.html)
- [Change working copy location](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Change-working-copy-location/qaq-p/452647)

Answer (score 1):

Clone takes a parameter for what you want, so

git clone https://url hello

This will place the repo directories under hello, instead of the default repo name.